# Android virtual router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, android, chromecast

I just bought a Chromecast and unfortunately it requires at least three devices:

1. The Chromecast
2. A device to control the Chromecast (in my case a tablet)
3. A Wi-Fi router

I was wondering if there is a solution/app where I can setup a virtual router on my Android device that broadcasts a Wi-Fi signal but can also emulate a network connection between said router and the Android device, cutting out the need for a physical Wi-Fi router.

I know I can create hotspot with my mobile and use that as a router but I think its a bit clunky and not ideal for streaming.

Comment: I guess I am not sure what you asking here... WiFi hotspot is **EXACTLY** what you are looking for, it turns an android phone into a wireless router. If using hotspot is "clunky and not ideal" then how else do you propose to connect or what do you want to connect to? EDIT: Nevermind, I just noticed this question was over a year old.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a DLNA app.
my favourite is BubbleUpnp .
Start Hotspot on Android.
connect Cromecast to it.
open BubbleUpnp on android.
select Cromecast from Local Renderer.
play anything from Local Library.
done...